# Circle ci runs deploy section despite test failing

Tags: node.js, jestjs, circleci

Circle ci is running the deploy section of my circle.yml depsite the test section failing. I'd expect that if anything goes wrong in the test section, the deploy section wouldn't be run, but it is.

There's two command in the test section the second one fails with :

`npm run test:coverage -- --maxWorkers=2 returned exit code 1`

I do not seem to be the first one, and the oldest post is a few months old:
https://discuss.circleci.com/t/deployment-triggered-after-tests-fail/12356/3

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong ?
Ideas ?

circleci v 1.0

Comment: Does your build status stay/turn green ?

Comment: No the final build status is red

Comment: Waiting for better understanding of the behavior, as a fix not, a solution, I move the tests commands to the deploy section, which fails the build as soon as any command fails.

Comment: Did you try the `requires` phase? So the deployment phase shouldn't run unless your tests run and green.